# How to combine multiple hypothesis tests on the same data by different methods? (variant calling)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, multiple-comparisons

TL;DR Bioinformaticians often look for genetic mutations using multiple tools simultaneously and get different results. What is the proper way to combine the different results?

*Variant calling* is a genomic analysis method where we compare the genomic sequence of an individual with the *reference* genome for that species (e.g. the human genome) and "call" individual bases (ACGT) as a variant if they don't match the reference.

```
Location: chr9 18754
reference:          AACATTTGTCAC
test:               AACAGTTGTCAC
                        ^
                      variant
```

In practice, the sequencing process creates multiple "reads" for each location in the genome (e.g. chromosome #, position). In fact, these reads may not even specify the same "base" (ACGT) at a given location. At any location, you can get multiple bases with different levels .of confidence.

Consequently, variant callers can't simply look for whether or not a base in the sequence matches the reference sequence. Different variant callers use different statistical models and can be more or less conservative. In a sense, each location in the genome corresponds to a hypothesis test:

**H_0**: *the base in the sequence is the same as the base in the reference sequence.*

In fact, variant callers will usually give you a p-value and/or other estimates of the quality of each individual "call."

It is common to use multiple variant callers on a given sample. I've not had luck finding discussions on how to statistically combine the results of different callers.

**NOTE:** I don't feel confident about the title for this post. I welcome suggestions for how to improve it.